# How to extract the types of argument from a function that was passed as argument?

Tags: typescript

I have functions that i want to wrap in another function, my problem is that i can't seem to find a way to extract the parameters of `baseReducer` and assign them to the returned function.

Also can i extract the types of the parameters of `baseReducer` and use them as types for `withLoadingState` parameters?

```
const START = 'START'
const SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS'
const ERROR = 'ERROR'

type Start = { type: typeof START }
type Success = { type: typeof SUCCESS; payload: string[] }
type Error = { type: typeof ERROR }

type State = {
  results: string[]
  loading: boolean
  error: boolean
}

export const initialState: State = {
  results: [],
  loading: false,
  error: false,
}

type ActionTypes = Start | Success | Error
const reducer = (state = initialState, action: ActionTypes) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state
  }
}

// I would also like to use the type of baseReducer action as the type
// of the parameters of withLoadingStates
const withLoadingStates = () => {
  // how to extract the types of state and action from base reducer
  // and assign them to state and action of the returned function
  return baseReducer => (state, action) => {
    const nextState = state // manipulate state but keep the same type
    return baseReducer(nextState, action)
  }
}

const wrappedReducer = withLoadingStates()(reducer)
```

Comment: Introduce the parameters of baseReducer into other variables, then u make parameters in withLoadingStates and replace them the same way u did down there, as an example withLoadingStates(state,action) { const tstate = nextState, and the same with the other one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some type parameters to capture the type of state and the type of action:

```
const withLoadingStates = () => {
  // how to extract the types of state and action from base reducer
  // and assign them to state and action of the returned function
  return <S, A>(baseReducer: (state: S, action: A) => S) => (state: S, action: A) => {
    const nextState = state // manipulate state but keep the same type
    return baseReducer(nextState, action)
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=38&ssc=2&pln=31&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAygFQIICUEwLwwOSNQ7AKFEljgFUBhSgUTjkxwurriJOhhpRQHkVG2bnxRFCUAJ4AHAKbwoAQwBOsLAG8Yk2QC5N0mSABm8ZGhgBfcfvgBXYMBkQIjDVpm63R+FVr0A3DBSChIANiAKACa60EoAlmAA5gDaALoWVrJcSkogSi56OgUGxsL86RlycIpQcuqEMDBKjjYhUBDRUHGJqfUwYZHxCboARiAgITIKYL0y2bkjYxNThJaEMgAeUrmwHLDxsVCxCiFVCjW6pzUuvU0QLW26qQA0vf0Rg7qGxxAyLw2zOSUn2+vxWhAqMCQwEO4AQ+mcWFOKhgAB9bPZHM40TQ5kpiOBOE0InZZowABTQM61GD7Q7HS6-GAKaGxcC6KEwsBw2QQACUmAAfDA1L0IAB3A7AAAWMDJzM5ADo3PyRQ0GhEZF97tpemrGjIoDYlGAYJSar1LKsAPRWmAASRgYpALQiTJCEBAfViAGs5FBPTYfpopX7rF5hgofigZMSHHl5ayTZHg6HZIQbTAvFAQ4FlAoALYG2bOLwS7MAGXC70SDIg+NIjoOUsrAxr1Uc5P5GCFqpgGalIDFmk9G068pTRRLxjNcimroT4Bghhy+ZgEaDRJJeIaGbnTKcsQSJuzMlX-tN7aZYHnLMXWZzTUNxpjS5sYFv0waj6NJoAPHAnkhAUyXXGRo1jWZdApdsLkAhcwHZLshTgJDZRnWCmQ-RDBWFXUYF2GAwFHBlGBnPtbXzKZYikFoqQvOjhhsWBfRkKQJwgAtUxkPDv2NNdIzAmMtzJIj1igBk4I-XkLTBetODFJQFCkWQInArdGDLZsq0GWsyV5MlNzjXkgA)

The type for `baseReducer` (`(state: S, action: A) => S`) will also ensure the reduce has an appropriate type

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted, but is it possible to use `A` to type `withLoadingStates` parameters?

Comment: You can move `A` to `withLoadingStates`, but that will validate that the parameter to `baseReducer` is the same as the parameter to  `withLoadingStates` which may or not be what you want

Answer (score 0):

I this what you are trying to do?

```
const START = 'START';
const SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS';
const ERROR = 'ERROR';

type Start = { type: typeof START };
type Success = { type: typeof SUCCESS; payload: string[] };
type Error = { type: typeof ERROR };

type State = {
  results: string[];
  loading: boolean;
  error: boolean;
};

export const initialState: State = {
  results: [],
  loading: false,
  error: false
};

type ActionTypes = Start | Success | Error;

const reducer = (state = initialState, action: ActionTypes) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

type FunctionParams<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> = F extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : any[];

const withLoadingStates = () => {
  return <F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(baseReducer: F) => (...[state, action]: FunctionParams<F>) => {
    const nextState = state; // manipulate state but keep the same type
    return baseReducer(nextState, action);
  };
};

const wrappedReducer = withLoadingStates()(reducer);
// mouseover > const wrappedReducer: (state: State, action: ActionTypes) => any;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nfldep